# SQL Server 2005 - Trigger Loop?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, triggers, rdbms

I am using triggers for the first time.

If I update a field in a table by an update trigger on the same table, with this spark a loop? Does sql server guard against this recursive behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190739.aspx) (search for `RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS`) describes some of the database settings you can use to modify this behavior.  Also, one way to safeguard your procedures is to use either the [`UPDATE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx) function or the [`COLUMNS_UPDATED()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329.aspx) function.

If, for example, you have a table with columns `A`, `B`, and `C`, and you want the value of `C` to change automagically when the value in column `B` is updated, you can protect the call in the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Whatever ON TableName AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF UPDATE(B)
    BEGIN
        /* Update column C here */
    END
END
```

This way you avoid calling the trigger recursively when column `C` is updated by your trigger.  `COLUMNS_UPDATED()` is also useful, but I find it to be fragile (relies on position of column instead of column name).

Answer (score 1):

You can control recursion of triggers at the DB level via the RECURSION_TRIGGER option; it's turned off by default. Even if this option is turned on, there is a limit of 32 nested levels of triggers; all changes will be rolled back if your exit condition didn't stop the recursion before reaching the limit of 32 levels.