# What happens when I use UPDATE statements in an AFTER UPDATE trigger?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to do some updating and inserting when a table gets updated to enforce correct data. Will putting UPDATE statements in the trigger cause a sort of "loop"?

Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer, but is there not a reason you can't validate the input data before you update the table in the first place?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2005 - Trigger Loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714935/sql-server-2005-trigger-loop)

Comment: I would take a good hard look at a design whereby a trigger on a table performs updates/inserts on the same table.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat - I just love having my data magically change on doing a standard insert or update. It makes debugging so much fun ;->.

Comment: @Mitch: grandmastery is when a mere `INSERT 1` into a single schema table results in a fully populated `Northwind`.

Comment: @Quassnoi: I guess that must be the kind of service they call 'Everything included'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating the target table in a trigger will make the triggers to fire again.

You may figure out the recursion depth using `TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()`.

The recursion will stop after `nested_triggers` repetitions (`32` by default) or if `RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS` is `OFF`.